# The pandas installed in my conda env is not the same version that the one used by python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in a High Performance Computing and I have been using a conda env. created by the team that supports this.

Today I have been getting strange error messages such as

```
PandasArray object has no attribute _str_len
PandasArray object has no attribute _str_contain
```

I think something is going wrong.

If I read a simple csv and then I print its content I get the first error I have put above in the line that print the data frame.

I have checked the pandas version using `conda list` and the version is 1.2. However, if I do

```
python
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print(pd._version_)
```

the output is 1.1.4

It is weird because when I do conda list, pandas 1.1.4 is not in that list.

Python version is 3.7.

I have also take a backup of my application to see if it is me but I have found same error I show you above. I cannot use for example `.str.replace()`

I have not idea what is going on but I would like to use pandas 1.2 to see if that fix the problem. How can I choose between version when running a script?

Comment: Try `import pandas; pandas.__path__` and see if that matches the Conda environment.

Comment: `pd._version_` should probably be `pd.__version__`. Best to copy-paste the exact commands/lines, or mistakes happen and people get confused.

Comment: Sorry, it is a type I have made I used pd.__version__

Comment: Since those error messages are about private Pandas methods, these should not be used in any code you are directly using. In that case, the version of Pandas doesn't matter: older versions that may miss such methods will simply not use those methods. So either those private methods are called explicitly (generally a bad idea), or something else is going on. But without the relevant code or backtrace, that can't be solved. We can (probably) only answer the actual question about the Pandas version.

Comment: I have get the path and I have look at that folder. I can see pandas-1.1.4-py3.7.egg-info/ and pandas-1.2.5.dist-info/

Comment: But where is that folder? Is it in the Conda environment? That is more important. You can also copy-paste the folder name here, and mask out any sensitive (e.g., user name) info.

Comment: /resources/conda/miniconda3/envs/sigprofilerextractor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas

Comment: Can I take this opportunity to ask. How can I create my personal conda env. from directories of other conda env. In this HPC I cannot install anything from internet. So, alternatively, I could create my own conda env, and avoid this

Comment: And `conda list -n sigprofilerextractor` still shows version 1.2?

Comment: yes. in the folder /resources/conda/miniconda3/envs/sigprofilerextractor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas, there are the 2 files I have mentioned before but also the folder pandas/ So the content is pandas/ pandas-1.1.4-py3.7.egg-info/ and pandas-1.2.5.dist-info/  . pandas/ is the 1.1.4 version what I think is the one imported by puthon isn't??

Comment: If you can't change your conda environment, you should ask the people who are responsible for it to fix this. There are two conflicting Pandas versions there, which really shouldn't happen. Pandas will need to uninstalled, probably partially manually (instead of with Conda), and then the correct version re-installed.

Comment: If you want to create your environment, you can create an environment file from the current one, adjust it as necessary, then create your own environment from that file. But please read through the Conda documentation first before doing that.